# Сделать словарь в словаре таким образом: ключи одного словаря являются значениями другого словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x, словарь

Помогите, пожалуйста. Уже всю башку сломала. Не знаю, как реализовать решение. Задача следующая:
Вам дан xlsx-файл с информацией о спортивных площадках в Москве https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZGnhkApWmAomxMQcdpGxIqGzrLWmMlMh/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113335581115004287089&rtpof=true&sd=true. Вам необходимо сдать на проверку json-файл, в котором будет храниться один словарь, ключами которого будут административные округа (AdmArea), а значениями словари, в которых, в свою очередь, ключами будут названия районов (District), относящихся к этому административному округу, а значениями - списки адресов площадок (Address) в том порядке, в котором они встречались в исходном файле.
Я написала код, где создала два отдельных словаря: один словарь с ключом "AdmArea" и значениями "District". Второй словарь с ключами "District" и значениями адресов "Address".

```
from collections import defaultdict
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\\Users\\Asus\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\task_9_4_1_data-25290-2019-09-30.xlsx')
fout = open('outa12.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8')

d1 = dict()
d2 = dict()
d3 = dict()
d4 = dict()
res1 = defaultdict(list)
sheet = wb['Sheet0']

for i in range(2, sheet.max_row+1):
    area = sheet.cell(row=i, column=5).value
    distr = sheet.cell(row=i, column=6).value
    addr = sheet.cell(row=i, column=7).value
    res1[distr].append(addr)
    d1.setdefault(area, []).extend(distr.split(','))
print(res1)
for key, value in d1.items():
    d2.setdefault(key, []).extend(value[i] for i in range(len(value)) if i == value.index(value[i]))
print(d2)
```

Теперь надо создать словарь, который будет выгдядеть примерно так:
{"Северо-Западный административный округ": {"район Строгино": ["улица Исаковского, дом 24, корпус 1", "Неманский проезд, дом 9"], "район Северное Тушино": ["улица Свободы, дом 56", "улица Свободы, дом 56", "улица Свободы, дом 56", "улица Свободы, дом 56"], "район Покровское-Стрешнево": ["Иваньковское шоссе, дом 6"], "район Щукино": ["Сосновая улица, дом 3, строение 2"]}, ...}
Мне удалось добиться результата, но через списки. Как сделать это так, как указано в примере? Как вложить один словарь в другой?
Буду очень признательна за помощь и идеи.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

areas = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

areas['area1']['district1'].append('addr1')
areas['area2']['district2'].append('addr2')

#{'area1': {'district1': ['addr1']}, 'area2': {'district2': ['addr2']}}
```